# Why doesn't my form work on one server. but does on the other?

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I'm using two webhosts. On one of these hosts it will let me use my form and receive the input per mail. The other host will tell me that it's been sent but I won't ever receive anything.

I've looked around here and the only thing I could find is that it might have something to do with PHPs sendmail, though I looked through the phpinfo() of both and it's identical (sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i )

Can anyone shed some light what I'm doing wrong here or what steps I should take?

P.S.:

I know this isn't best practice for a form, it just has to be very simple and work.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="formulierverzenden.php">
<ul>
<li>Je voornaam *</li>
<li><input type="text" name="voornaam" /></li>
<li>Je achternaam *</li>
<li><input type="text" name="achternaam" /></li>
<li>Je e-mail adres *</li>
<li><input type="text" name="email" /></li>
<li>Je berichtje *</li>
<li><textarea cols="50" rows="12" name="bericht"></textarea></li>
<li><input type="reset" value="Begin opnieuw" /> <input type="submit" name="versturen" value="Verstuur bericht" /></li>
</ul>
<p>Alle velden gemarkeerd met een * zijn verplicht.</p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
$naar = 'ik@marcianoplanque.nl'; // Waar moet het naartoe?
$onderwerp = 'Contactformulier (je site)'; // Het onderwerp van het bericht

// Header instellen, zodat nl2br() werkt
$headers = "MIME-version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";

if(isset($_POST['versturen'])) // Als het formulier verzonden is door op de verzend knop te klikken
{
  $voornaam = trim($_POST['voornaam']); // Alle overbodige spaties uit het voornaam veld verwijderen
  $achternaam = trim($_POST['achternaam']); // Alle overbodige spaties uit het achternaam veld verwijderen
  $email = trim($_POST['email']); // Alle overbodige spaties uit het email veld verwijderen
  $bericht = trim($_POST['bericht']); // Alle overbodige spaties uit het bericht veld verwijderen
  $fout = false; // Om te kijken straks of er wat fout is

  if(empty($voornaam)) // Als het voornaam veld niet is ingevuld
  {
    print '<p>Helaas, het voornaam veld is verplicht maar is nu niet ingevuld!</p>';
    $fout = true; // Zorgen dat het script zometeen weet dat er wat fout is
  }
  if(empty($achternaam)) // Als het achternaam veld niet is ingevuld
  {
    print '<p>Helaas, het achternaam veld is verplicht maar is nu niet ingevuld!</p>';
    $fout = true; 
  }
  if(empty($email)) // Als het email veld niet is ingevuld
  {
    print '<p>Helaas, het email veld is verplicht maar is nu niet ingevuld!</p>';
    $fout = true;
  }
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Als het email adres niet correct is
  {
    print '<p>Helaas, het email adres is niet correct!</p>';
    $fout = true;
  }
  if(empty($bericht)) // Als het bericht veld niet is ingevuld
  {
    print '<p>Helaas, het bericht veld is verplicht maar is nu niet ingvuld!</p>';
    $fout = true;
  }

  if($fout == false) // Als er niks fout is (alles is dus netjes ingevuld)
  {
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $voornaam . ' ' . $achternaam . '<' . $email . '>'; // Een afzender instellen zodat je kan reageren.

    if(mail($naar, $onderwerp, nl2br($bericht), $headers))
    {
      print '<p>Het bericht is succesvol verzonden!</p>';
    }
    else
    {
      print '<p>Helaas, er is wat fout gegaan tijdens het verzenden van het formulier.</p>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I, really, not gonna read a code with non-english named variables and comments

Comment: My guess is, the SMTP server configuration is different for both servers. Double check SMTP settings. Also, I don't know what's the comments are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of things that could be going wrong, but if it works on one server but not the other, it's very unlikely that it's your code, especially for something like this, where PHP version isn't going to make much of a difference.

It sounds like server configuration, and there are a lot of things that can go wrong there.  First step: look in the logs.  Syslog, as always, PHP error logs, sendmail logs.  See if there are any errors, Google them, track them down.  Can you send mail from the problematic server using the sendmail command-line tools?  It's just gonna be a process of narrowing down what is and isn't working.

My wild-stab guess: the mail is being queued to sendmail (thus PHP is doing its job and returns an "all done, everything went well" message), but something is preventing sendmail from actually sending the mail out (ports being blocked, maybe?), so the messages are just sitting in the local queue waiting to be sent.

That's probably not right because it's a wild guess, but it's likely the type of problem you'll find.